# Data Migration tools for SpringBoot<>Aerospike

Tags: spring, liquibase, flyway, aerospike

We are exploring Aerospike as a data store for one of our upcoming projects.

As part of same, I want to check if there is any migration tool available for Aerospike to work along with Spring similar to liquibase or flyway migrate.

Usecase: Insert/Update data around config on application startup and maintain changelog.

We can write code and do it ourselves on application startup but looking for a neater out-of-the-box solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Flyway does not currently support Aerospike. I am not aware of any migrations tool that support it.

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation from Aerospike about migrations? https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/manage/migration

Comment: There's also a question on their forum asking a very similar question, but it is from 2015, so it may not be accurate anymore. They refer to this document for solutions to the issue: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/udf.html and the original question is https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/db-migration-framework-for-aerospike/1197